# How do I convert nibbles to values in 6502 assembly?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I am working on a decompression algorithm for a binary format that stores screen files for my NES project.  The NES screen resolution is 260x240.  I am creating meta-tiles in 2x2 pixel format.  The compression format will designate which 2x2 files should be written to the screen.

The format I have chosen will be written as

```
0000xxxx: right nibble = value of tile 1 - 16
xxxx0000; left nibble  = number of times a tile is written on that row 1 - 16
```

In the above example, **11110001** would tell the import routine to write tile 1, 16 times.

The part I haven't figured out is how to take the left nibble and convert it to hex.  The same problem I have is to take the right nibble and use it as a value as well.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this using bitwise ops or not.  I need an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Isn't the NES 320x240?

Comment: It's actually 256x240.  The sprite location registers are 8 bits wide, and a single nametable is 32x30 tiles.  It's not 256x256 likely so there was room for attribute tables.  On the Commodore 64 where the resolution can be 320x240, the sprite location registers have a ninth bit (all the ninth bits are in their own register).

Answer (score 4):

Given your "compressed" (though "packed" would be a better term) data in .A, you should do this:

(Assuming `tile_id_to_write` and `write_it_this_many_times` are zero page locations you want to unpack this to.)

```
lda packed_data,X             ;or however you're iterating through the packed data
and #%00001111                ;strip off top 4 bits; this is what AND dones
sta tile_id_to_write          ;store that somewhere
lda packed_data,X             ;get the original packed data again
lsr                           ;shift right 4 times
lsr 
lsr 
lsr
sta write_it_this_many_times
```

Depending on how you're reading the packed data you may do something different than `lda packed_data,X`.  I'm pretty sure `lsr` puts a 0 in the most siginificant bit.  Remember the rotate instructions spin the carry back around to the most significant bit so you usually want to do `asl` or `lsr` for shifting or multiplying/dividing by 2.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out:

The way to do this is to do the following:

```
val = %11110001
LDA #val
AND #%00001111 ; mask left nibble
STA rightn
LDA #val
AND #%11110000 ; mask right nibble
ROR
ROR
ROR
ROR ; rotate high bits 4 times
STA rightn
```

Comment: You should use `LSR` rather than `ROR`; otherwise you'll get the wrong result if carry is set before beginning your code. Also the second `AND` could be omitted.

Comment: @Tommy Absolutely, ASL/LSR are usually the better choice for this kind of bit-twiddling unless you NEED the Carry rotated in. That second AND is superfluous *IF* the OP uses LSR since it rotates zeros in from the left, so pre-masking the lower nybble out is a waste of cycles. Additionally, you could use TAX after the first LDA and then TXA instead of the second, to save a byte and 'n' cycles (depending on the addressing mode of the LDA). Or live dangerously and use LAX the first time, eliminating the TAX. Oh, and that final 'STA rightn' should be 'STA leftn'.